# Facebook login error: Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.:

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

I am creating a facebook login on my site, following this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

I started out by creating an app on facebook, then used the app ID in my code. After completing step 2 in the guide, i wanted to test for errors. I keep getting the above error "Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings...."

To resolve the issue, i tried to change the app website URL to http://www.mywebpage.com/index.html. That didn't do anything....

Any ideas?

Thanx
[image: index.html]

Comment: check if [this](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191/4691841#4691841) will help you.

Comment: what exactly have you tried? what's your App Domains settings? is it `mywebpage.com`?

Comment: It's very simple, really. I put http://www.mywebsite.com/ in the app domain settings. Let me paste my index file for you in my original question

Comment: Ok, i tried again with mywebsite.com in the 'app domain' field. Strange that facebook didn't put this in their tutorial....:/

Comment: great! just added an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Also double check your app ID. I was using a test app id while developing locally and forgot to switch it back to the real app ID.

Comment: Thank you! Was very close to spending hours on this one - good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your App settings. Usually absolute URLs can cause errors. Adding the root URL (without `www` if you have subdomains) `mywebsite.com` in your App domain would probably solve your issue.